# Fredholm Integral Equation and Neumann Series (understanding a proof)

Tags: functional-analysis

I am having trouble understanding an "easy to see" observation in Classical Theory of Integral Equations by Zemyan regarding the Fredholm integral equation:

Consider $(C[a,b],|| \cdot||_{\infty})$ and the equation $$f(x) = \lambda u(x) - \int _a ^b k(x,y) u(y) \, dy \qquad{(1)}$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ (here, $\lambda \neq 0$ and $k(x,y) \geq 0$ is continuous on $[a,b] \times [a,b]$ and $f \in C[a,b])$. Define the operator $K: C[a,b] \to C[a,b]$ by $$K u(x) = \int _a ^b k(x,y) u(y) \, dy .$$

> It is easy to rearrange (1) to find (using Neumann series, see Theorem 2.2.1) that $$||K|| = \text{max} _{x \in [a,b]} \int _a ^b |k (x,y)| \, dy.$$ Assuming $||K|| < |\lambda|$ ensures the existence of a solution $u$ to (1).

Could someone explain the part I highlighted in detail? It is not "easy" for me to see, all I could do is rewrite (1) as $f= (\lambda I - K) u$, and I do not think this is the arrangement that the author had in mind to use the theorem. The theorem involving Neumann series is below:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $L$ a bounded linear operator in $X$. If $||L|| < 1$ ($L$ is a contraction) then $I - L$ has a bounded inverse in $X$ satisfying $$(I - L)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} L ^n \text{ and } ||(I - L)||^{-1} \leq \frac{1}{1 - ||L||},$$ where $I$ denotes identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|K\| < |\lambda|$, then $L := \frac{1}{\lambda}K$ is a contraction. Hence you can apply the theorem to the problem $$(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}K)u=\frac{1}{\lambda}f$$
and get that $$u =(I-\frac{1}{\lambda}K)^{-1}\frac{1}{\lambda}f$$

To find the expression for $\|K\|$, observe that $$\|K\| = \sup_{u \in C[a,b], \|u\|_{\infty}\leq 1} \|\int_a^b k(\cdot,y)u(y)\|_{\infty} \leq \|\int_a^b k(\cdot,y)dy\|_{\infty}$$

However as $[a,b]$ is compact, the "sup" of the infinity norm becomes a max and we get $$\|K\| \leq \max_{x\in [a,b]}\int_a^b k(x,y)dy$$

To show the reverse inequality, simply pick $u \equiv 1$ on $[a,b]$.

Note : the absolute value of $k$ is not needed because $k$ is assumed to be $\geq 0$.

Comment: That makes sense, I did not think of finding an actual solution the way you did. How can we show that ||K|| has the form stated in the highlighted part, though?

Comment: I've edited my answer to completely answer your question.